# C++ STL::list == operator

Tags: c++, stl

I have to implement doubly linked list with STL::list.
Here is my class:

```
#ifndef LISTSTL_H_
#define LISTSTL_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
 #include <assert.h>

namespace util{

template<class T>
class LinkedList{
std::list<T> llinked;
typename std::list<T>::iterator it;

public:

LinkedList(){
        this->it = this->llinked.begin();
    }

void add(const T e){
    this->llinked.push_back(e);
}

int size(){
    return llinked.size();
}

void remove(int k){
    assert (k>=0) && (k<=size());
    std::advance(this->getIterator(),k);
    this->llinked.erase(this->getIterator());
}

void remove(const T& e){
    this->llinked.remove(e);
}


typename std::list<T>::iterator getIterator(){
    return this->it;
}

const T& operator[](int k){
    typename std::list<T>::iterator it = this->getIterator();
    std::advance(it,k);
    return (*it);
}
 };

 }



#endif /* LISTSTL_H_ */
```

I want to use it with elements of type Expense which I defined it . I defined the following operators for it:

```
int Expense::operator ==(Expense& e2) const {
if(amount == e2.getAmount()){
    return 1;
}
return 0;
} 

int Expense::operator<(Expense& e2) const{
if(amount<e2.getAmount()){
    return 1;
}
return 0;
}


bool Expense::operator !=(Expense& e2) const {
return amount != e2.getAmount();
}
```

But still I get the error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/list.tcc:249:4: error: no match for ‘operator==’
in ‘__first.std::_List_iterator::operator* 
[with _Tp = domain::Expense, std::_List_iterator::reference = domain::Expense&]() == __value’
```

Does anyone know why ?
Thank you!

Comment: Semi-related: it makes good practise to have the arguments to your operator overrides be const references, eg. `const Expense& e2`. You shouldn't be modifying the argument anyway, and there are various constructs that can benefit from it.

Comment: Could you give us a [minimal complete example](http://www.sscce.org)? It would save us a lot of work.

Comment: Thank you for wanting to help me ! Actually the advice of Rook has helped me. After making const the error has disappeared . Again thank you ! The StackOverflow community is awesome :)

Comment: You don't need to save the begin iterator `it`, as it is already stored inside `linked`. By storing it you might run into the problem the iterator is invalidated when you remove the first element of the list. Just call `llinked.begin()` instead of `getIterator()`

Comment: THank you Jasper ! I have modfified it.